# Unknown "D" variable on datasheet's max pulse current description

Tags: datasheet

I was reading the [datasheet](https://www.osram.com/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-2496274/SFH%204545.pdf) for an SFH4545 IR LED. In the "maximum ratings" category, the "surge current" value's conditions are: $$t_p=100\mu\text{s},\,D=0$$
What does the D mean? At first, I thought it could be the duty cycle, but it'd be strange if it was 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D is indeed a duty cycle as can be seen from the charts in the datasheet provided:
[image]

\$D = 0\$ is a strange value given this definition and accompanying \$t_p = 100\mu S\$ which is making this configuration impossible for periodic pulses as it drives \$T\$ to infinity, so it is probably referring to a single pulse.

Comment: And what would \$D=0\$ mean? Monostable?

Comment: I'd say they're probably referring to a monostable pulse

Answer (score 0):

A little later down in the datasheet it provides a small equation for D and it does in fact look like it is duty cycle

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The duty cycle approaches zero as the period approaches infinity.  If it's a single pulse, the period is infinity (mathematically...we interpret it as "so long it doesn't matter").

Answer (score -2):

So I ran your equation through google, and found the BioMon Sensor Datasheet, down at the bottom on page 10, it says: [image: Photo of datasheet] Duty Cycle D = Parameter. I believe this is what you're looking for. However, it does seem odd that the duty cycle is set to 0...